# Logo nudged down from the top of the page. Not sure why

Tags: php, html, css, graphical-logo

On my site for one particular page the logo is nudged down a few pixels, while on all the other pages it is not. The code is identical(at least I think it is) for all pages so I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

Here is a screen shot of a working vs non working:

Working:

[image]

Non-Working:

[image]

The code for both is shown below however for some reason, one of the pages doesn't render correctly

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper"><?php include("include/header.php"); ?>
```

header.php:

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1 class="hidden">Welcome</h1>
    </div><!-- #logo -->

<?php include("getstageinfo.php");
switch ($currentStage)
{                       
case "0":

    $home ="period0.php";
break;

case "1":

    $home ="period1.php" ;

break;

case "2":

    $home ="period2.php" ;

break;

case "3":

    $home = "period3.php";

break;

}
?>
<nav id="nav">
    <h1 class="hidden">Main Navigation</h1>
    <a class="nav-item current" href="<?php echo $home ?>">HOME</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="news.php">NEWS</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="accounts.php">ACCOUNTS</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="logout.php">LOG OUT</a>
    <div id="nav_edge">&nbsp;</div><!-- #nav_edge -->
</nav><!-- #nav -->
</header><!-- #header -->
```

CSS:

```
body { background-color: #031311; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; position: relative; background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center top; overflow-x:hidden; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6em; color: #2a2d32; }
#header { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 350px; display: block; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
#header #logo { background-image: url(../images/logo.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center top; display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 450px; width: 100%; }
#header #nav { position: absolute; height: 50px; width: 455px; left: 50px; top: 298px; background-image: url(../images/nav_bg.png); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: left top; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-top-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: #8C9791; border-bottom-color: #8C9791; border-left-color: #8C9791; }
#header #nav .nav-item { font-size: 14px; line-height: 50px; color: #E1E7EA; display: inline-block; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 15px; font-style: italic; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 15px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; }
#header #nav #nav_edge { background-image: url(../images/nav_edge.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left top; display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 52px; width: 40px; position: absolute; top: -1px; right: -40px; }
#header #nav .nav-item:hover, #header #nav .nav-item:focus { color: #FFF; }
#header #nav .nav-item.current { color: #2BD5CC !important; }
```

And here is the generated html for working:

[image]

And here's the non working:

[image]

Comment: This is probably a CSS problem, what we really need to see is the generated HTML for a page where it works and the page where it doesn't, along with the relevant CSS.

Comment: Might well be a CSS issue, did you check that?

Comment: provide the link, or at least the html and related CSS. not possible to tell anything with the code provided.

Comment: Ok I've added the CSS and provided the generated html

Comment: After looking at it again, the entire page is shifted down, excluding the background image.

Comment: Reeeeeally need to see actual HTML, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that it was to do with the include(); functions I was using before declaring the doctype. So I asked a new question. See below

[PHP include() before doctype, causing a white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131265/php-include-before-doctype-causing-a-white-space/9131347#comment11492483_9131347)

Answer (score 0):

for css purpose IE7 different from IE8 and they all differnet from FIREFOX, CHROME....

I dont see you specifying css file for IE7 using

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You need to have alternate css for IE7 in your page

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I am not concerned about any other browser except Chrome at the moment.

Comment: OP said the problem happens only on a single page; besides, he didn't mention IE7 in particular

Comment: Well in that case I think I got it wrong - But there is way to check it - use firebug in Firefox OR inspect element on Chrome.  - you need to make sure what styling or attributes are being used for image on one page is same as other pages and not being overwritten by other stylings or css files...