# PHP include() before doctype, causing a white space

Tags: php, include, whitespace

I have a website with a white space problem. I am including a few files before the doctype
and this is causing a white space to be outputted.

After searching I have found this solution:
[Problem with whitespace before doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749011/problem-with-whitespace-before-doctype)

However after removing `?>` I am still getting the problem. Below is the code:

```
<?php
include ("include/session.php");
include ("include/updatestage.php");                                        
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>....
```

Here is `session.php`:

```
<?php session_start();

// if a team name has been assigned to a session...
if ( isset($_SESSION ['teamName']))
{

//create "global variable $teamName that can be used across all pages as long as the function "session_start(); is present"
$teamName = $_SESSION ['teamName'];

}
else{

die ( "You are not logged in! Redirecting to login page...<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='2; url = index.php'>");

}
```

Here is `updatestage.php`:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
//update stage

$inserted="n";
mysql_query ("UPDATE `team` SET `inserted`='$inserted' WHERE teamName = '$teamName' ");

$advance="n";
mysql_query ("UPDATE `game` SET `advance`='$advance' ");
```

Here is `getstageinfo.php`:

```
<?php
include("include/config.php");
//Select the slogan from the current user
$currentStage = mysql_query("
SELECT `currentStage` FROM `team` WHERE `teamName` = '$teamName'
");
//assign the text located at the logo field (the path of the logo) to a variable $slogan
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($currentStage);
$currentStage= $row['currentStage'];
?>
```

And finally here is `config.php`:

```
<?php
// connect to database
$con = mysql_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx"); 

if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

// select database 
mysql_select_db ("xxxxxxx");          
?>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Ok so I have added back in the ?> and tried the suggestions below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
include("include/session.php");
include("include/updatestage.php");
?>
```

Or trying:

```
<?php

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n";

include ("include/session.php");
include ("include/updatestage.php");

?>
```

Produces:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at public_html/period1.php:2) in public_html/include/session.php on line 1
```

Trying:

```
<?php
include("include/session.php");
include("include/updatestage.php");
?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Or:

```
<?php

  ob_start();

  echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n";

  include ("include/session.php");
  include ("include/updatestage.php");

  ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Still produces the white space.

Comment: copy and paste `session.php` and `updatestage.php` into a plain text editor, like notepad and then re-copy and paste pack to your document. Also, make sure in those two files there are no white spaces before the beginning `<?php` or after the ending `?>`.

Comment: Found the problem, it was the nested `include("config.php");` rather than including I just pasted the code into `updatestage.php`

Comment: The problem, then, is likely whitespace in `confuig.php`

Comment: One more thing to check while you're in a text editor - see if you have Byte Order Mark (BOM) disabled - this should be somewhere in the encoding options (ex. `UTF-8+BOM` may indicate trouble).

Comment: I removed the `?>` as I was following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749011/problem-with-whitespace-before-doctype

Comment: ok ill try your recommendations

Comment: I have not yet tried these methods however just letting you know I have included the config in my edit above for viewing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to fix the problem like this:

```
<?php
include ("include/session.php");
include ("include/updatestage.php");                                        
?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

But I have observed buggy behaviour in this respect (although not since PHP4), so the easiest solution that guarantees a fix is to put the `<!DOCTYPE>` before the include - since neither included file outputs anything, and would break your document if it did.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php

  include ("include/session.php");
  include ("include/updatestage.php");

?>
<!-- Rest of HTML -->
```

Or this:

```
<?php

  echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n";

  include ("include/session.php");
  include ("include/updatestage.php");

?>
<!-- Rest of HTML -->
```

Remember to make sure that the `<` in the opening `<?php` tag is **the first** character in all files if you go with the second option.

**EDIT** Having in the first place completely failed to take into account the session/cookies problem that has reared it's ugly head, here is a working solution:

```
<?php

  ob_start();

  echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n";

  include ("include/session.php");
  include ("include/updatestage.php");

  ob_end_flush();

?>
<!-- Rest of HTML -->
```

Comment: Still no joy with the new code, bare in mind I still have the `?>` at the end of the include files.

Comment: @user1064028 Well the `?>` in your included files should be removed because those files don't output any HTML (this is a good rule of thumb for whether you want one or not) but if you are still getting white space before the doctype now, even with output buffering, and having ensured your opening `<?php` is at the very first character in your file, you probably have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your script file. Do you have a link to your page you can give me so I can have a look at it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7318/discussion-between-daverandom-and-user1064028)

Comment: So turns out it was a BOM issue

Comment: @user1064028 So I see. I have logged out of it now, and just as an experiment I thought I'd do the sign-up form to look for SQL injection holes - you'll be please to know I didn't find any, but I think your inserted data is being double-escaped, I signed up with a team name of `test'` and `anothertest"` and when I log in they display as `test\'` and `anothertest\"` - have you called `addslashes()` *and* `mysql_real_escape_string()` by any chance?

Comment: @user1064028 Also you need to pass database data through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before outputting it into HTML. I also created a user `test>` and it outputs that string literally onto the page, it needs to appear in the HTML as `test&gt;` to avoid the risk of breaking your page layout, which `htmlspecialchars()` will take care of for you.

Comment: Hi DaveRandom, I have strip_tags() for the inputs but that's it do i need addslashes(), addslashes() also?

Comment: You should just use `htmlspecialchars()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`, there is no need for `strip_tags()` or `addslashes()` if you use them. `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used for *every* bit of user input that is used in an SQL query, and `htmlspecialchars()` should be used for *every* bit of user input that is output onto a page. If you do that, you are pretty much safe. There are other things that you can do which are even safer, but for the purposes of a uni project the two methods above are all you need. Look into PDO parameterised queries if your interested.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to remove the `?>`. Just the whitespace after it. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
include ("include/session.php");
include ("include/updatestage.php");                                        
?><!DOCTYPE HTML>....
```

Comment: If you don't intend to output HTML from a PHP file, then you _should_ leave out the `?>`.

Comment: In the main script, yes.  But not in the _other_ PHP files he's including, which is where the actual problem was.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  You have to encode "UTF-8 without BOM" for the file you are **including**.

The master php file doesn't necessarily have to encode with "UTF-8 without BOM", and in fact I'd recommend that you don't if you have certain special characters (caused problems for me).

Was also answered here:  [PHP include causes white space at the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199355/php-include-causes-white-space-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

OK, these steps should fix your problem:

1. Go through *all* PHP files on your site.  If the file ends with `?>` (and possibly some whitespace), remove the `?>`.  (Of course, if there's some HTML text after the `?>` then you shouldn't remove it.)
2. While doing the above, also check that there's no whitespace in front of the first `<?php` in any files.
3. If you still have problems after that, check for invisible characters in front of the `<?php`.  There are several ways to do that, but looking at a [hex dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) of the files is one good way.  The first two bytes of each PHP file (that doesn't begin with HTML text) should be `<?` (hex `3c 3f`).

In the unlikely event that those steps won't solve the problem, let us know (and preferably include a link to a page where the problem occurs, so that we can check the output ourselves).

Answer (score 0):

Open file in Notepadd++
From top bar: Encoding->Encode in UTF8 without BOM
Save the file
In Dreamweaver

Press CTRL + J or go to Change->Page Settings->Tile/Encoding and unchek UNICODE BOM if it is cheked.