# Page is loading differently when included via PHP

Tags: php, html, header

If I make this the code of index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin: 0px;
            }
    
            header{
                height: 100px;
                background: #000000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

then it displays how I want it, like this: [image: correct]

But then, when I change index.php to:

```
<?php
require "./includes/header.php";
?>
```

and then have header.php as the *exact* same code that I posted just then, a blank space appears above the header:

[image: incorrect]

Why?! What could cause a page with the *exact* same HTML (I've checked multiple times) to display different when included via PHP, especially since the browser wouldn't even have any knowledge of what goes on server-side...

Anyone know?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you are including the correct file which has the same content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's encoding problem, you need to save your file with "UTF-8 without BOM".
Look at [PHP include causes white space at the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199355/php-include-causes-white-space-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
    require_once('includes/header.php');
```

and header.php file must inside includes folder.

Comment: Not true at all, you're free to `require` whatever PHP you want. Besides that, parentheses are unnecessary for language constructs like `require`.