# Twig {% include %} generates undesirable whitespace

Tags: php, twig

I have this code in `index.twig` (snippet formatted exactly as shown):

```
<div style="width: 12.5%; float: left; text-align: left; padding-right: 7.5px; padding-top: 5px;">{% include "_nav.twig" %}</div>
```

And this is my `_nav.twig` (snippet also formatted exactly as shown):

```
<nav>
    <ol class="linkSection">        
        <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
        <li id="nav-expand-collapse" class="isCollapsed"><a href="#">Expand All</a></li>
    </ol>

    <ol class="linkSection">
        <li class="h2">Research</li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=research_intro">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=research_intro">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=research_intro">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=research_intro">Spam</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?p=research_intro">Eggs</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

This is the expected output (notice the lack of spaces between the heading and the Index link:

[image: Expected Output]

What happens is that Twig would include unnecessary whitespace like so:

[image: Actual Output]

This is what I see in the Chrome Development Console (Notice the `""`):

[image]

I have tried `{%- include -%}`, `{% spaceless %}` around the `<div>` and `{% include|trim(" ")`, but none of them succeeds at getting rid of the whitespace. How can I get rid of these whitespaces?

All files are encoded in UTF-8. The problem seems to be gone when I encode as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Is your file encoded with UTF8- without BOM?

Comment: @Tib Used to, but all files have been converted to UTF-8. _nav.twig is a new file.

Comment: @Tib I lied - it turns out that I left one file unconverted. However, this made me discover that files encoded in UTF-8 without BOM do not have this issue.

Comment: It looks like [Twig used to not like BOM at all](http://symfony2forum.org/threads/6-Twig-error-A-template-that-extends-another-one-cannot-have-a-body-..). I wonder if this is related to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the encocoding to UTF8 without BOM.
It happen when you use the function `include`, I guess it's the same with Twig.

Related problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200440/1235943

> When you save a page as UTF-8, a special signature called a byte-order
>   mark (or BOM) is included at the beginning of the file, indicating
>   that it is a UTF-8 file. You can only see BOMs with low level text
>   editors (such as DOS edit). You need to remove this signature from the
>   included file in order to get rid of the white space at the top of the
>   page.

Answer (score 1):

do you have an error in your `_nav.twig` ?
See here:
`li><a`

Comment: Oops - that was not in the original code. Fixed. The error is not related to that typo however.

Comment: What about `{% include`. Do you need a space there?

Comment: Pretty sure Twig parses them just fine. As I said, my very original code was `{% include "_nav.twig" %}`.