# Why my php include add a (text) -- > " "?

Tags: php, html, include

I include a PHP file in my code:

```
<body>
    <?php include 'defaults/menus.php'; ?>
    <a href='commons/logout.php'>Logout</a>
</body>
```

It's the code that i add on the original code: (defaults/menus.php)

```
<div id='menu-superior'>

</div>
<div id='menu-lateral'>

</div><div>
```

And the chrome add a () text. Image:

> [image]

And this generate this problem:

> [image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr0vjjfp/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/kr0vjjfp/embedded/result/)).

A whitespace in the visual.

the css is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@font-face {
    font-family: Ebrima;
    src: url(ebrima.ttf);
}
body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Ebrima; 
}
html{   
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#menu-superior{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    widht:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#646464;   
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you see this in the browser or only in the debugger?

Comment: It seems to be that it is being caused by some part of code above the php code, are you sure there is no piece of code above the php include which might cause the error?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with my Chrome (39.0.2171.95) on Windows 7. In `defaults/menus.php` a `<div>` is opened but never closed. Can you try to replace `position:relative;` with `position:absolute;`?

Comment: I tried to do this, but the problem continued to occur. I will try reinstall the php, because any 'include' I do it my unconfigures ' html'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of my problem was:

> In Notepad++ you can change the encoding of the file to "UTF-8 without BOM" from the "Encoding" menu."

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199355/php-include-causes-white-space-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome debug toolbar displays a whitespace as a space within quotes even if it's only a whitespace between HTML tags. Look at the original source code of the page with `Ctrl + U` (or *Tools > More tools > Display source*) and you will see that they are no quotes in the HTML rendered file. This is not a problem, there's nothing to fix.

If you want to remove the spaces, then don't insert anything between `<body>` and the `<?php tag`:

```
<body><?php
    include 'defaults/menus.php'; ?>
```

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Área Restrita</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id='menu-superior'></div>
<div id='menu-lateral'></div> <a href='commons/logout.php'>Logout</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: When i go to original source, show this, but in the visual part have a whitespace, and i don't how i can remove this...

Comment: Can you just show us all relevant code? So the CSS, HTML and PHP involved.