# Codeigniter : source code top white space

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am working on codeigniter application.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7NyP.jpg)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEs13.jpg

please check above image for source code.

here top of page i am getting empty space and 15 line coding has been starting

Please any once can suggest, how my code start with 1 st line.

Comment: Have you included any file top of the page?

Comment: May be your issue is similar with this 
please check : [php-include-causes-white-space-at-the-top-of-the-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199355/php-include-causes-white-space-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

The white space lines must be removed from the header template view where your header view is attached to body view.

Check the Controller first, then find which header is rendered for that page where you see the empty lines.

I hope it will help!